# How does ChannelFactory (WCF/C#) use an Interface as a type?

Tags: wcf, channelfactory

Looking at creating Channels explicitly in WCF, you do this:

```
IService channel = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, address).CreateChannel();
```

Why am I allowed to 'type' the channel factory as an interface? I know that the `IService` interface has to be decorated to allow this. what is ChannelFactory doing behind the scenes to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, `ChannelFactory<TChannel>` creates an object of type `ServiceChannelProxy`, which derives from [System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy(v=vs.110).aspx), allowing it to create a [transparent proxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973857.aspx#hawkremoting_topic3) over the `TChannel` interface.

Comment: It's funny that WCF is based on .net remoting...I did not know that.

Comment: While .NET remoting as a distributed technology is dead, much of its infrastructure is absolutely core to .NET (including all the AppDomain stuff). Not sure how much of it goes away in .NET core, yet.